# Hibernate @Where clause missing from JOIN FETCH

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpql

I have the following 3 entities: `Item`, `Warehouse` and `ItemWarehouse` which has `item_id` and `warehouse_id`. I've set up the `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` relationships on the 3 tables. In addition, I use soft-deletes, so each Entity has `@Where(clause = "deleted_flag = 0")`.

I wrote a query to fetch all items that goes like this:

```
SELECT i FROM Item i
JOIN FETCH i.itemWarehouses iw
JOIN FETCH iw.warehouse
```

The JPQL converts to this statement on the console:

```
select
    // fields
from item item0_ 
inner join item_warehouse itemwareho1_ on item0_.id=itemwareho1_.item_id and ( itemwareho1_.deleted_flag = 0) 
inner join warehouse warehouse2_ on itemwareho1_.warehouse_id=warehouse2_.id 
where ( item0_.deleted_flag = 0)
```

It is visible that the first `inner join` and the last `where` clause contain `deleted_flag = 0` but the 2nd `inner join` doesn't. Why is that?

My Entities are defined like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Where(clause = "deleted_flag = 0")
class Item

@Entity
@Table(name = "item_warehouse",)
@Where(clause = "deleted_flag = 0")
class ItemWarehouse

@Entity
@Table(name = "warehouse")
@Where(clause = "deleted_flag = 0")
class Warehouse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this problem. It turns out that this is a hibernate 6.x bug which was fixed with version 6.2.0.CR4; see the Hibernate ticket [@Where not consistently applied across association boundaries](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16019)